# Converting express app object into a type rather than a value

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

Im trying to setup my own ts express project and trying to abstract the code as much as I can.
In my app.ts i have the following code

```
import express from 'express'


const app = express();
const port = 3000;
require('./routes')(app)


app.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    return console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});

export default app
```

Im basically trying to move all routes that are configured in this app to a seperate folder to make it easier to navigate.

Then in my routes.ts i have this code

```
const testController = require('./controllers/test')
import app from './app';


module.exports = (app) => {
    app.get('/test',
        testController.testingRoute)
}
```

So whenever i try to run the script or even look at the code it errors with `Parameter 'app' implicitly has an 'any' type` and then if i do `app:app` it errors with `'app' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.`

I would not want to disable type checking in tsconfig, i think its the whole point of TS, so how should i approach this ?

Comment: It's already typed. Just define it as `module.exports = (app: express.Application) => ..`. Make sure you npm install `@types/express`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the express.Router class, which was built for this usecase:

```js
// router.ts
import express from "express"
const testController = require('./controllers/test')

const router = express.router()

router.get("/test", testController)

export default router
```

```js
// app.ts
import express from 'express'
import router from './router'

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.use("/", router)

app.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    return console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});

export default app
```

Check out http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#router for more information

Answer (score 0):

As @slebetman posted a comment below the question. The solution would look like

```
const testController = require('./controllers/test')
// import app from './app';
import { Application } from 'express';

module.exports = (app: Application) => {
    app.get('/test',
        testController.testingRoute)

}
```